# Textbox not accepting value greater than 50000 after 5th key press using jquery

Tags: jquery

The task is very simple. I'm trying to give values in a textbox which should be numeric and it should not be greater than 50000. However it is checking only after 6th key press. I've given the max length of the textbox as 5.

Here is my code.

```
// Kit price should be only numbers and less than 50000
$('.kitprice').keydown(function(e) {

    var value = $(this).val();
    value = value.replace(/^(0*)/,"");
    $(this).val(value);
    if ($.inArray(e.keyCode, [46, 8, 9, 27, 13, 110, 190]) !== -1 ||

        (e.keyCode == 65 && e.ctrlKey === true) ||
        (e.keyCode >= 35 && e.keyCode <= 39)) {
            return;
    }

    // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
    if ((e.shiftKey || (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57)) && (e.keyCode < 96 || e.keyCode > 105)) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }

    if(parseInt($(this).val()) > 50000) {
        alert('Kit price should not be more than 50000');
        return false;
    }
});
```

It works only on 6th key press, but I want to check on 5th for eg 50001, it should give me alert.

Thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

just  change

```
$('.kitprice').keydown(function(e) {
```

to

```
$('.kitprice').keyup(function(e) {
```

Comment: It will take alphabets too if I use keyup.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `keyup` instead of `keydown`, see below code

```
$('.kitprice').keyup(function(e) {

    var value = $(this).val();
    value = value.replace(/^(0*)/,"");
    $(this).val(value);
    if ($.inArray(e.keyCode, [46, 8, 9, 27, 13, 110, 190]) !== -1 ||

        (e.keyCode == 65 && e.ctrlKey === true) ||
        (e.keyCode >= 35 && e.keyCode <= 39)) {
            return;
    }

    // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
    if ((e.shiftKey || (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57)) && (e.keyCode < 96 || e.keyCode > 105)) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }

    if(parseInt($(this).val()) > 50000) {
        alert('Kit price should not be more than 50000');
        return false;
    }
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bb4j8ooa/14/)**

Comment: The input textbox is taking alphabets. Can you please prevent this?

Comment: Yes, its taking alphabets too. :(

Answer (score 1):

You want to check the value ***after*** the key has been pressed, so you should attach this function to the `keyup()` event instead.